# Postgres 9.4 detects Deadlock when read-modify-write on single table

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, deadlock

We have an application with a simple table

```
given_entity{
    UUID id;
    TimeStamp due_time;
    TimeStamp process_time;
}
```

This is a spring boot (1.2.5.RELEASE) application that uses spring-data-jpa.1.2.5.RELEASE with hibernate-4.3.10.FINAL as jpa provier.
We have 5 instances of this application with each of them having a scheduler running every 2 second and querying the database for rows that have a due_time of last 2 mins until now that are not yet processed;

```
SELECT * FROM given_entity 
WHERE process_time is null and due_time between  now() and NOW() - INTERVAL '2 minutes' 
FOR UPDATE
```

Requirement is each row of above table gets successfully processed by exactly one of application instances.
Then the application instance processes these rows and update its process_time field in one transaction.
This may or may not take more than 2 seconds, which is scheduler interval.
Also we don't have any index but PK index on this table. 
Second point worth noting is that these instances might insert rows this table which is called separately by clients.

Problem: in the logs I see this message from postgresql (rarely but it happens)

```
ERROR: deadlock detected
Detail: Process 10625 waits for ShareLock on transaction 25382449; blocked by process 10012.
Process 10012 waits for ShareLock on transaction 25382448; blocked by process 12238.
Process 12238 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on tuple (1371,45) of relation 19118 of database 19113; blocked by process 10625.
Hint: See server log for query details.
Where: while locking tuple (1371,45) in relation "given_entity"
```

Question:
  How does this happen? 
  I checked postgresql locks and searched internet. I didn't find anything that says deadlock is possible on only one simple table.
  I also couldn't reproduce this error using test.

Comment: can you paste the code where you update the table? **select for update** blocks modifications by other transactions, one should be careful with it.

Comment: to avoid these issues altogether, you can use Hibernate optimistic locking mechanism (unless there is some really valid reason to lock records which you want tio update). Perhaps this might also be helpful:  http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-read-modify-write-cycles/

Comment: For update we just update the process_time field in. something like 'UPDATE given_entity set process_time= now() where id = ?'

Comment: And for optimistic lock we couldn't use it because the requirement was that each row must be processed exactly by one instance. With optimistic lock, two instances could concurrently process the row and when the second one gets OptimisticLockException, it is too late and that row is already processed. We wanted to keep it simple and used DB row lock to synchronize different instances of our application.

Answer (score 2):

Process A tries to lock row 1 followed by row 2. Meanwhile, process B tries to lock row 2 then row 1. That's all it takes to trigger a deadlock.

The problem is that the row locks are acquired in an indeterminate order, because the `SELECT` returns its rows in an indeterminate order. And avoiding this is just a matter of ensuring that all processes agree on an order when locking rows, i.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM given_entity 
WHERE process_time is null and due_time between  now() and NOW() - INTERVAL '2 minutes' 
ORDER BY id
FOR UPDATE
```

In Postgres 9.5+, you can simply ignore any row which is locked by another process using `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So If I understand it correctly, postgresql will find the result of 'SELECT... ' and then goes for locking the result rows. Is that why your suggested solution will avoid the problem?

Comment: That's right, locking is done after sorting: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/2382.1170171581%40sss.pgh.pa.us

Answer (score 1):

This can easily happen.

There are probably several rows that satisfy the condition

```
due_time BETWEEN now() AND now() - INTERVAL '2 minutes'
```

so it can easily happen that the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` finds and locks one row and then is blocked locking the next row. Remember – for a deadlock it is not necessary that more than one table is involved, it is enough that more than one lockable resource is involved. In your case, those are two different rows in the `given_entity` table.

It may even be that the deadlock happens between two of your `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` statements.
Since you say that there is none but the primary key index on the table, the query has to perform a sequential scan. In PostgreSQL, there is no fixed order for rows returned from a sequential scan. Rather, if two sequential scans run concurrently, the second one will “piggy-back” on the first and will start scanning the table at the current location of the first sequential scan.

You can check if that is the case by setting the parameter `synchronize_seqscans` to `off` and see if the deadlocks vanish. Another option would be to take a `SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table before you run the statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was also suspicious about different order of scanned rows. But since I couldn't reproduce it in unit test with 100 threads concurrently writing and 100 threads concurrently reading, I wasn't sure if that's the case. One more thing that I couldn't explain was that why an 'AccessExclusiveLock' is acquired here? Is that because at the same time an insert is going to happen and postgresql wants to reindex PK? I'm not sure how 'synchronize_sequence=off'  will affect our performance. Do you think an index on search columns asking  result can mitigate this?

Comment: As for 'SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE' I'd rather not to go for explicit lock if I have other choice.

Comment: And more importantly 'SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE' is conflicting with more other locks than 'ROW SHARE' which is acquired with 'SELECT FOR UPDATE'.  I'm not sure how it affects the performance.

Comment: An index on `due_time` is probably a good idea. I don't think locking is a great idea either, but if you do: an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE LOCK` would be way too strong, `ROW SHARE` is not strong enough as it does not conflict with itself.

Answer (score -1):

Switch on hibernate batch updates in your application.properties

```
hibernate.batch.size=100
hibernate.order_updates=true
hibernate.order_inserts=true
hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size = 400
```